# How to define "M-x find" in the same way as "M-x grep"?

Tags: emacs

I am looking for a command `M-x find` in Emacs, which behave exactly like `M-x grep` (allows to modify the command, prints the output nicely including links to the found files, ...) and which executes `find . -iname '*|*'` (with the cursor placed at the vertical bar -- for inserting a search pattern -- if not too complicated to implement). Has anyone implemented this before? [I am aware of `M-x find-grep`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-dired` that does almost what you want: it reads directory from minibuffer, defaulting to current directory, and then reads other `find` arguments. The result is opened in `dired` mode, and I think it's as nicely as it can get (if you think that `dired` is too verbose, check out `dired-details` and maybe `dired-details+` packages at [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/)).

Now let's make it start with `-iname **` with a cursor between the stars when it's asking for options. Looking at `find-dired` source, we can see that it uses the value of `find-args` as an initial input argument to `read-string`. This argument is obsolete and deprecated but awfully useful. One of its features (as we read in `read-from-minibuffer` description) is providing a default point position when a cons of a string and an integer is given.

```
(defun marius/find-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((find-args '("-iname '**'" . 10)))
    (call-interactively 'find-dired)))
```

We added single quotes around stars in `'**'` because the arguments are subject to shell expansion.

Instead of reading our own arguments from the minibuffer, we just
rebind `find-args` and delegate all the rest to `find-dired`. Normally
`find-dired` remembers last arguments you enter in `find-args` so they
become the new default. Rebinding it with `let` ensures that this
modification from *our* call to `find-dired` will be thrown away, so
regular `find-dired` will use the arguments given to the latest
*regular* `find-dired`. It probably doesn't matter if you don't use regular `find-dired`. If you *want* find arguments given to our wrapper to be used by regular `find-dired`, use the following definition instead:

```
(defun marius/find-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (setq find-args '("-iname '**'" . 10))
  (call-interactively 'find-dired))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `find-dired` fulfills your requirements (except it doesn't initialize the command with "-iname" and lets you enter it).

For example:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-dired`<kbd>RET</kbd>  *(execute `find-dired`)*
- <kbd>C-j</kbd>  *(accept default directory : `.`)*
- `-iname "*.foo"` <kbd>RET</kbd> *(enter command-line arguments)*

Results are presented in a `dired` buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
(defun eab/find-grep ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
        (grep-find-command
         `(,"find . -iname '**' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep -nH -m 1 -e \"^\"" . 17)))
    (call-interactively 'find-grep)))
```

Also I use:

```
(defun eab/grep ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
        (grep-command
         `(,(concat "grep -i -nH -e  *."
                    (ignore-errors
                      (file-name-extension buffer-file-name))) . 16)))
    (call-interactively 'grep)))
```

EDIT: Now grep-find-command is for searching only first line of each file by default.