# dired: M-x find-dired: disable history?

Tags: emacs, dired

I set `(setq find-args "-iname ")` so that `M-x find-dired` gives me ... "Run find (with args): -iname " as default. However, it seems to remember its history. Is there a way to disable the history and always start with the default argument "-iname"? I tried to modify `find-args-history` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the function `marius/find-dired` each time instead of `find-dired`, as it is showed in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593263/1937596). E.g. setup something like this `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'marius/find-dired)`. It calls `(setq find-args "-iname ...")` each time before calling `find-grep`.

EDIT: without renaming:

```
(setq find-args '("-iname '**'" . 10))
(defadvice find-dired (after eab-find-dired activate)
  (setq find-args '("-iname '**'" . 10)))
```

for deactivate:

```
(ad-remove-advice 'find-dired 'after 'eab-find-dired)
(ad-deactivate 'find-dired)
```

EDIT2: We use `after-advice` here, see comments.

Comment: ahh... good! Is it possible to bind it to `find-dired` itself [no renaming]? [or, if not possible, bind it to `M-x find`]

Comment: Can you explain why you need binding without renaming? It isn't usual way.

Comment: I don't really need to name it `find-dired` as well, I was just interested in how one would do it without redefining the whole function. Something which would be more practical would be to have it work on the shorter `M-x find` (which isn't used for anything as far as I see). But when I start the definition with `defun find ()`, I only get TAB completion to other functions such as find-*.

Comment: You should use `(interactive)` in your definition `(defun foo () (interactive) ..)` then it appears in `M-x`. Also, function `find` is traditionally defined in `cl-seq.el`. You can use your personal name, e.g. `name/find`. See EDIT.

Comment: Is your first chunk `(defadvice...)` complete? It does not work in my case, I just get the original definition of `find-dired`. Concerning `(interactive)`: I had this. Indeed, I used exactly the second chunk as posted in the answer you link to and replaced `marius/find-dired` by `find`.

Comment: Sorry, it should work with "before", but it doesn't. With "after" it works this way: after executing `find-dired` variable `find-args` becomes `'("-iname '**'" . 10)`. And next time you get what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23633/discussion-between-artscan-and-marius-hofert)